# Branching Process - Calculate the variance of total number of people

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Here's the problem.

> The following model can be used to describe the number of women (mothers and daughters) in a given area. The following model can be used to describe the number of women (mothers and daughters) in a given area. The number of mothers is a random variable X∈Po(λ). Independently of the others, every mother gives birth to a Po(μ)- distributed number of daughters. Let Y be the total number of daughters and hence Z=X+Y be the total number of women in the area. Compute E[Z] and Var[Z].

Now I mange to compute Var(X), Var(Y), E[X] and E[Y]. Since Var(Z) = Var(X) + Var(Y) + 2 Cov(X,Y), I have to compute E[XY]. Can anyone help me with E[XY]? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using total law of expectation

\begin{align}
E[XY] &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty E[XY|X=k]Pr(X=k) \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty kE[Y|X=k] Pr(X=k) \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty k(k\mu) Pr(X=k) \\
&= \mu \sum_{k=0}^\infty k^2Pr(X=k)\\
&= \mu E[X^2]
\end{align}

I will leave the rest as an exercise.